# django query compare charField with Float

Tags: django

Im trying to search objects between a latitude and longitude.
The problem is that the objects latitud and longitude are charFields and when I try to compare it doesn't have the negative in mind.

```
models.py:
class myModel(models.Model):
    latitud = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    longitud = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)

views.py:
    def myFunc(request):
        max_lat = 2.23245
        min_lat = 1.12232
        max_lon = -1.0023
        min_lon = -3.12345
        #With latitude no problem because is positive

        try:
            tokiak = Tokia.objects.filter(
                latitud__lte=lat_max,
                latitud__gte=lat_min,
                longitud__lte=lon_max,
                longitud__gte=lon_min
        )
```

How can I take the '-' into account??
Is better to change the CharField to FloatField/DecimalField? (I prefer not)

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is better to change the CharField to FloatField/DecimalField?

*Yes*

At the minute you're trying to fit square pegs in round holes and thats always going to be a problem, your data types should *always* accurately represent the data they hold. Numbers should *always* have a numerical data type.. *always*.

Comment: I put like this in my model: latitudea = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=25, max_digits=28, blank=True, null=True) and didn't lost dataBase information. Thx

Comment: @KarramarroGorri - No worries, glad it helped

Comment: Don't forget the limitations of floating point arithematic, if it's important to you that decimals are stored exactly, use DecimalField and not FloatField.